# Analysis of discontinuous+split function

Tags: algorithm

Given

[image: this function]

This is clearly a discontinuous function. I am asked to find whether this function is in Big Oh, Big theta or Big Omega of another function namely T(n)=n!

I am not even sure about the position of  n0 point because of the discontinuity. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function, in terms of Big O notation, can be considered as:

`f(n) = 3^n * 3 * log_3(3^n) = n * 3^(n+1)`

This is true because it is said that for `n >= 10^5` the function is defined in this way.

Notice that it doesn't matter how big values of a function are under for arguments `x < x0`, where `x0`is a constant. Intuitively, we are only interested how the function grows when its argument grows to infinity.

From Wikipedia:

> That is, `f(x) = O(g(x))` if and only if there exists a positive real
>   number `M` and a real number `x0` such that
>
> `|f(x)|<= M * |g(x)|` for all `x >= x0`

Thus, you can simplify the function to:

`f(n) = n * 3^(n+1)`

and then compare it to your `T(n)`.

Comment: so in this case f(n)=omega(T(n)), by considering 10^5 as x0

Comment: it depends on `T(n)`, if you have `T(n) = n!` then `f(n) = O(T(n))`, because `n!` grows faster than any exponential function, and `f(n)` is exponential function multiplied by a polynomial, which doesn't change anything,